# Usage of len() to get number of array indexes

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, string

This is regarding a simple Python function. How come I can read the values in the array x, but not get the number of indexes, even though they are correctly stored in the array.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('empty_book-kopi.xlsx').parse('Sheet 1')
x=[]
x.append(df['Numbers'])
print("Print method says  :  ")
print(str(x))
print('\n')
print("Lenght method says : ")
print(str(len(x)))
```

This is the Excel column that I'm importing from and the terminal output:

[image: Terminal_output]
[image: Excel_column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append `df['Numbers']` to the list `x`, the list will contain a single element and that element will be the Series named `Numbers`. Instead, you want to include the items in that Series so you need to use the `list.extend` method.

```
In [11]: x = []

In [12]: x.append(df['Numbers'])

In [13]: len(x)
Out[13]: 1

In [14]: x.clear()

In [15]: x.extend(df['Numbers'])

In [16]: len(x)
Out[16]: 3
```